# Cannot open dockerized .net core api on custom port

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

**docker-compose up myapp.sample.api**

```
Creating network "myapp_frontend" with the default driver
myapp-sample-mssql-cnr is up-to-date
Creating myapp-sample-api-cnr ... done
Attaching to myapp-sample-api-cnr
myapp-sample-api-cnr       | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
myapp-sample-api-cnr       |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {daa358c7-8c64-4e3c-90ea-06f48de12ad4} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
myapp-sample-api-cnr       | Hosting environment: Development
myapp-sample-api-cnr       | Content root path: /app
myapp-sample-api-cnr       | Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
myapp-sample-api-cnr       | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Problem here is that I cannot open my web api app on this specified port

```
http://localhost:5000
```

returns **Could not get any response** from a postman

> Locally I am able to open this app through visual studio debug.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
    frontend:
    backend:

services:
    myapi.sample.api:        
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: MyApi.Sample.API/Dockerfile
        image: myappsampleapi-img          
        container_name: myapp-sample-api-cnr    
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        networks:
            - backend
            - frontend
        depends_on:
            - mssqlserver

    mssqlserver:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest"
        ports:
            - "1445:1433"

        container_name: myapp-sample-mssql-cnr        
        networks:
            - backend
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ...
...
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.Sample.API.dll"]
```

I am not able to get any log output from the api container

**`docker logs -f myapp-sample-api-cnr`**

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {82dd75ea-8302-4859-a3e5-78eedf856e34} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

**Edit:**
I tried to change Dockerfile to expose port 5000 instead of 80

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
```

and on docker ps -a I'm getting

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                   NAMES
964724837d13         myappsampleapi-img                   "dotnet MyApi.S…"   45 seconds ago      Up 43 seconds       5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32788->80/tcp   myapp-sample-api-cnr
```

Still having the same problem, cannot get response from api on `localhost:5000`

Comment: Can you show your logs of the 'myapi.sample.api' container ?

Comment: For some reason I am not able to get log output from my container. Locally it works.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is the container running ? (docker ps -a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yml file, the `myapi.sample.api` service runs a process which gives the following log:

```
...
Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
```

which means that your process is listening on port `5000` bound to the **container IP address**.

You also used the [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) directive to publish a port opened within the container on another port opened on the *docker host*. Remember that each container has its own IP address which is different that the one of your docker host. In the docker world, *publishing a port* means *opening a port on the docker host which is connected to a port of a container*.

The `ports:` directive syntax is:

`HOST:CONTAINER`

or in other words:

`<port to open on the docker host>:<port already opened within the container>`

Since you seem to be wanting to connect to port `5000` of your container by connecting to port `5000` of your docker host, the `ports:` directive should be :

```
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are mix the ports in the composer file.

It should not be 80:5000 ?

> Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen).

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: I'm not sure about this cause I'm able to access sql server on containerized port 1445 using same approach. I still tried to switch to 80:5000 but its still the same problem.

Comment: Dockerfile should expose 5000 to, isn't it ?

Comment: Tried that to expose 5000 instead of 80, remove image, rebuild it again but still the same problem. Question udpated.

Comment: make it `- "5000:5000"`

Comment: @Thomasleveil that actually work. Can you please elaborate a bit and post as an answer I'll accept it